# Import serial doesnt work after using pip install pyserial

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, pip, pyserial

After installing pyserial, I still get the error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial'"

This is the beginning of the code:

```py
import serial  
import time  
import serial.tools.list_ports
```

And these are the problems:

```py
Import "serial" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports) [1, 8]  
Import "serial.tools.list_ports" could not be ... Pylance(reportMissingImports) [3, 8]
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you really did install `pyserial` it must be installed in a different version of python than the one you use to run your code.

Answer (score 1):

`pyserial` is an annoying package.
Although you install it using `python3 -m pip install pyserial` you need to import it using `import serial`. Linters have a hard time seeing that the installed package `pyserial` corresponds to the module `serial` you are trying to import.

In your specific case I'd suggest editing VSCode's `settings.json` and adding:

```
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportMissingImports": "none"
}
```

This suppresses the Missing Imports warning.

Comment: You are right, and probably this is related to the existence of the "serial" module https://pypi.org/project/serial/:  "A framework for serializing/deserializing JSON/YAML/XML"

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @quamrana.

You can check which pip you are using through `pip --version`, and which python you are using through `where python`(cmd) or `get-command python`(PowerShell). Make sure pip matches up with the python interpreter you are using.

If it's not, you can try to reopen the terminal with the shortcut 'Ctrl+Shift+`'. And then to check the pip version again.

If it still doesn't matches up with the interpreter. That's maybe this environment hasn't installed the pip in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have:

python --version

```
Python 3.11.0
```

pip --version

```
pip 22.3.1
```

code --version

```
1.74.2
```

In my case require was only restart vs code